# Check if the connection is up

Tags: hyperledger-composer

As a client, I wanted to know if a connection to the peer is still alive.
`BusinessNetworkConnection` as a function to connect and to disconnect, but no event system which can say "The connection was lost"

The only way, I saw, is to use `BusinessNetworkConnection.ping()`, but call this function before each others is a little bit inelegant

Is there a way to have this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this issue
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3013
for more details about connection reliability that has gone into Composer 0.19. 
It also provides more detail about the current thought process. Hyperledger Fabric is a distributed ledger and as such just because one peer in the network is not contactable doesn't mean that transactions can't be submitted and committed to the blockchain.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not for the peer network, but it can come from the application itself. It could be fine if an event can be thrown when the connection between peers and the application has gone for any reason (firewall problem, VPN problem, broken cable, ...)

Comment: As that issue explains there isn't a way to know if a peer has gone away. A composer connection isn't a persistent connection to all peers in the network.